# How to use HAML to generate standalone HTML files via a layout template

Tags: web, haml

I use `haml` a lot when developing web applications but for the job I am doing right now all the client needs is flat `HTML` files and some `javascript`. There are quite a few files I thought it might be easier to code them all up using `haml`, with a layout file to capture the stuff common to each page.

I checked the `haml` docs and they offer a simple example:

```
haml hello_world.haml hello_world.html
```

that happily generates a hello world page from my template.  I've scoured the docs for information on how I could get it to recognise a `layout.haml` file however but have not had any luck.

The goal is to set up a directory structure like

```
/
 - templates/
    - layout.haml
    - other.haml
    - pages.haml
 - output/
```

and from command line just go

```
haml templates output
```

and generate `other.html` and `pages.html`

Is this possible, or am I looking at the wrong tool for this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd look at using [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) with a HAML workflow something like this http://mikeferrier.com/2011/04/29/blogging-with-jekyll-haml-sass-and-jammit/

Comment: The link is broken, please do not post links. Instead, take your time to spell out the solution here on SO. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org) is pretty good too.. possibly simpler than jekyll in some ways, though with less goodies

Comment: nanoc looks amazing actually.  Thanks.