# Can you only use HAML in a Ruby on Rails project?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, haml

The question is pretty straight forward. I've been familiarizing myself with [HAML](http://haml.info/) and I just wanted to know if using it in a Rails project is the only way to use it? Forinstance, can't I use HAML in just a normal static website project that I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me refer you to:

[How to use HAML to generate standalone HTML files via a layout template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242144/how-to-use-haml-to-generate-standalone-html-files-via-a-layout-template)

and the link in the answer:

[Blogging With Jekyll, Haml, Sass, and Jammit](http://mikeferrier.com/2011/04/29/blogging-with-jekyll-haml-sass-and-jammit/)

as an example of HAML being used outside of a RoR project

Comment: Absolutely spectacular!

Answer (score 1):

Browsers don't understand HAML explicitly. It needs to be interpreted by some kind of engine that will return the HTML that it describes. There are implementations for HAML in pretty much every web language, though. Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haml#Implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Check out middleman - http://middlemanapp.com/ it is a static site generator.  It's built in Ruby but it will allow you to create a static site using haml without rails.  I'm guessing it is similar to [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/).

Answer (score 0):

From the [Haml docs](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#using_haml):

> Haml can be used in three ways:
>
> - as a command-line tool,
> - as a plugin for Ruby on Rails,
> - and as a standalone Ruby module.